# How to draw a line which cross two points but spans across the X direction using Plotly Python?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I plotted a candlestick chart (X axis being timeseries, Y axis being stock prices) with a segment (the blue one) which started from a datapoint and ended with another datapoint
[image]

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')
print(len(df['Date']))
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],
                open=df['AAPL.Open'],
                high=df['AAPL.High'],
                low=df['AAPL.Low'],
                close=df['AAPL.Close'])])

fig.add_shape(type='line',
              x0=df['Date'][200], y0=df['AAPL.Open'][200],
              x1=df['Date'][400], y1=df['AAPL.Open'][400],
              line=dict(color='blue', width=3),
              xref='x', yref='y')
fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.show()
```

Now I want to turn the segment into a line i.e., it still crosses the same two datapoints, but it now starts from the left of the plot area and ended on the right of the plot area (the purple one).

[image]

My first try was to find out the coordinate the datapoints on the canvas, so I can come up an equation of a line formula, thus calculate the start point and the stop point of the longer line, but I can't find such method that I can feed the raw data (for instance `x` being the time and `y` being the price of that time) and give me the canvas coordinate of that set of data (`x` being 0~1 and `y` being 0~1 or something else).

Is there a better way for me to plot a line across two data point? thanks!

Comment: Is your question asking how to calculate a line like a trend line? Or are you asking for another way to draw a line?

Comment: @r-beginners Yes, I'm trying to draw a trend line, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue searching for a plug-and-play solution or you can create it yourself.
A datetime is normally converted to an integer by your graphing tool. Most of the time it is "seconds since Jan 1, 1970". You can compute it with python datetime.datetime.timestamp().

A straight line is defined by equation y = m * x + b.
Your 2 data points belong to the line so you can compute m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1) and then b = y2 / (m*x2).
Find the X coordinates of your graph borders and compute:
y3 = m * x3 + b and y4 = m * x4 + b

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I forgot that timeseries are also numbers, now I can implement a trend line in my plot!